# How to get the running instance of a Contract

Tags: solidity, truffle

I have a contract with name `AuxContract` and imported it in my `Dapp.sol`.

In my `Dapp.sol` I have a variable of type `AuxContract`which I want to initialize with a running instance of an `AuxContract`contract which I have its address.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Just doing something like this:

```
import './relative/path/to/AuxContract.sol';

contract Dapp {

    AuxContract aux;

    function Dapp(address auxContractAddress) {
        aux = AuxContract(auxContractAddress);
    }
}
```

The aux contract is written in another file in you path (or could be a stantard library too), the thing you do importing is just like having the contract written in the same file.

In this case, one `AuxContract` instance should be previously deployed and you should have its address.

Comment: It's cool you are asking and answering your own questions. But be carefull not to minimize your effords, could you for example comment the code snipped or explain how exactly this solves the question ask, e.g., where is the AuxContract declared and where initialized?

Comment: where to run `import`? on geth console? if so why `contract Dapp {` is there it throws error `> import '/home/ether/contracts/simplestorage.sol';
(anonymous): Line 1:1 Unexpected reserved word
`

Comment: In truffle you can import other contract files.